# Using a php variable inside an sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my php script,i am using a php variable inside an sql query.The php variable acquires its value through a post variable as follows:

```
$desc0=$_POST['desc0'];
$desc1=$_POST['desc1'];
$desc2=$_POST['desc2'];
$desc3=$_POST['desc3'];
$desc4=$_POST['desc4'];
$desc5=$_POST['desc5'];
$desc6=$_POST['desc6'];
$desc7=$_POST['desc7'];
$desc8=$_POST['desc8'];
$desc9=$_POST['desc9'];
```

The query is:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
$q="insert into photos(name,category,description) values ('{$name{$i}}','$category','{$desc{$i}}')";
}
```

The problem is that on submitting the form i am getting an error which says 
**"undefined variable desc"**.
Therefore its not taking the values from the previously defined variables?
Any help?

Comment: change this $desc{$i} to $desc$i and it should work

Comment: Don't build SQL queries blindly. Use [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, you code is completely unsafe - you should not pass user data directly into your query. There are many topics about it, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) is a good start.

Next, you don't need to store your data in such weird way. What if you'll want to pass 20 photos? In HTML, name your fields like `photos[]` - and in PHP, your values will be correctly parsed as an array `$_POST['photos']`, so you will be able to work with array:

```
$photos = $_POST['photos'];
foreach($photos as $photo)
{
   //$photo contains certain item, so handle it with your logic
}
```

Finally, your issue is because of non-obvious PHP possibility for array-dereference with curly brackets. So your `$desc{$i}` is an attempt to access `$i`-th index for non-existent array `$desc`. Either use `$desc$i` or use concatenation to separate your variables.

Comment: Doyou are right.i too was not finding it appropriate to use 10 variables but i am familiar with only basic php but want to master it...Searching a proper direction.@Alma

Answer (score 0):

You must change `$desc{$i}` to `${"desc" . $i}`